# CSS selector efficiency

Tags: css, browser, performance, css-selectors

I'm interested in way browsers apply CSS rules.

Though I know that there is no real difference, I'm wondering if it's more efficient to....

- Constrict range of elements

> ```
> a.external
> /*instead of*/
> .external
> ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Surprisingly](http://www.css-101.org/descendant-selector/go_fetch_yourself.php) `a.external` is usually **less** efficient than `.external`. The reason is that browsers usually match selectors backwards, that is, first they find all elements with class `external` and **then** filter out all elements which are not links.